# Underscore conditionals and operations for this template?

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

New to underscore. How do I write an "each" function for each post so that only the latest post is appearing? I know the logic is something like this

```
<% _.each(posts, function(post, index) { %>
<% if(index % 3 == 0) { %>
```

But I only want the LAST post to show. In addition to that, I'm trying to figure out the logic I wrote in comments before each section, I'm having trouble trying to figure out the **if/then** logic code if ONLY an image appearing, if ONLY text, and then when if an image AND text appear together.

```
<!-- TEXT ONLY -->
<p><%= post.message %></p>
<!-- /TEXT ONLY -->

<!-- IMAGE ONLY -->
<img class="imgonly" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE ONLY -->

<!-- TEXT + IMAGE -->
<p><%= post.message %></p>
<img class="imgtext" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE + IMAGE -->

<!-- TEXT + IMAGE + LINK + LINK SUMMARY -->
<p><%= post.message %></p>
<p class="link"><a href="<%= post.link %>" target="_blank"><%= post.link_title %></a> - <%= post.link_summary %><\/p>
<img class="imgtext" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE + IMAGE + LINK + LINK SUMMARY -->

<!-- IMAGE + LINK + LINK SUMMARY -->
<p class="link"><a href="<%= post.link %>" target="_blank"><%= post.link_title %></a> - <%= post.link_summary %></p>
<img class="imgtext" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE + LINK + LINK SUMMARY -->

<!-- PLACEHOLDER -->
<p><i>There are currently no updates. Please check back soon.</i>   </p>
<!-- /INITIAL PLACEHOLDER -->
```

Comment: Use `_.last(posts)`?

Comment: Does wrapping  _.last(posts) around this code guarentee the last post uploaded to render to the browser? Also, if I can get help with the if/then logic question I originally asked as well, that would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try something like that:

```
<% if (posts.length !== 0) {      
   var post = posts[posts.length-1];  
%> 

<% if (post.message) { %>
<!-- TEXT ONLY -->
<p><%= post.message %></p>
<!-- /TEXT ONLY -->
<% } %>

<% if (post.image) { %>
<!-- IMAGE ONLY -->
<img class="imgonly" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE ONLY -->
<% } %> 

<% if (post.message && post.image) { %>
<!-- TEXT + IMAGE -->
<p><%= post.message %></p>
<img class="imgtext" src="<%= post.image %>">
<!-- /IMAGE + IMAGE -->
<% } %> 

...

<% } %>
```

Comment: Can you explain this part: 
    <% if (posts.length !== 0) {      
   var post = posts[posts.length-1];  
   %>

Comment: Just a way to safely extract last item out of an array. If array is empty the whole code is skipped all together (see last <% } %> in the end). If array is not empty we can safely get the last element by its index and do all the rest of the code with it.

Comment: Ah I see. How do I write the logic for when this conditional, '<% if (post.image) { %>’ should only render if the post  has only an image, vs '<% if (post.message && post.image){ %>’ will render when text and an image is uploaded? Otherwise the image uploads twice when an image only is uploaded.